# How to handle Post Request send to an Angular Azure Static Web App

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, azure-static-web-app

I am building a new website to replace our existing one, which is currently a php site hosted at [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com). The new site is an angular app, published to an azure static web app using SWA. It has an asp.net core Web API back end, which is published to an azure web app. Currently the angular site is accessed via [www.mysite-new.com](http://www.mysite-new.com) and the api is accessed via api.mysite-new.com. Our current desktop app sends post requests to [www.mysite.com/tools/licence.php](http://www.mysite.com/tools/licence.php). When I switch the dns over so that our new angular site is on [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com), i still need the post requests to be processed. I tried setting up staticwebapp.config.json to redirect /tools/licence.php to the new end point on api.mysite.com/api/services/app/tenant/GetLicence but it does not work. I am assuming this is because the redirect does not send the post data with it? Are there any other options I should look at? I get that Angular is front end and it is the server that needs to deal with the post data but I cant find anything online that looks like it might be the answer?

Comment: Handling POST requests in an Angular Azure Static Web App involves working with both the Angular application and the server-side (Azure Functions or other serverless functions), do you have such functions ?